# Using kura framework, how can I specify the address type to "random static" when connecting to a BLE device

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, bluetooth-lowenergy, kura

I'm trying to create an OSGi bundle that'd be installed on a eurotech gateway (reliagate 10 05). 
This bundle would  essentially connect the gateway to a BLE device.

To do so, I use a framework provided by eurotech called **Everyware™ Software Framework (ESF)** that adds up an extra layer on top of the **kura v1.2.0** framework.

The catch is, the BLE device only accepts random static address type.

I managed to connect the gateway manually to the BLE device using the following commands in console:

`hcitool -i hci0 lecc --random <BD_ADDR>`

then

```
gatttool -i hci0 -b <BD_ADDR> --interactive
```

This works fine. The hard part is when I try to do the same thing in code using the **ESF/kura** framework.

Here's a snippet from a sample I use that I found on this [page](https://esf.eurotech.com/docs/how-to-use-bluetooth-le)

```
public boolean connect(String adapterName) {
    this.bluetoothGatt = this.device.getBluetoothGatt();
    boolean connected = false;
    try {
          connected = this.bluetoothGatt.connect(adapterName);
    } catch (KuraException e) {
          logger.error(e.toString());
    }
    if (connected) {
        this.bluetoothGatt.setBluetoothLeNotificationListener(this);
        this.isConnected = true;
        return true;
    } else {
       // If connect command is not executed, close gatttool
        this.bluetoothGatt.disconnect();
        this.isConnected = false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is a list of some objects that the sample uses to scan and establish a connection:

```
org.eclipse.kura.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
org.eclipse.kura.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
org.eclipse.kura.bluetooth.BluetoothGattSecurityLevel;
org.eclipse.kura.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
org.eclipse.kura.bluetooth.BluetoothLeScanListener;
org.eclipse.kura.bluetooth.BluetoothService;
org.eclipse.kura.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
org.eclipse.kura.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
org.eclipse.kura.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
org.eclipse.kura.bluetooth.BluetoothLeNotificationListener;
```

So I searched through the api [doc](http://download.eclipse.org/kura/releases/1.2.0/docs/apidocs/) but didn't find anything.

Though, one interesting SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22151724/2445061) mentions a command code to send to the device.

I found a method in kura framework that might help. 
Here's the signature:

```
void ExecuteCmd(java.lang.String ogf, java.lang.String ocf, java.lang.String parameter)
```

but I couldn't figure out the OpCode Group Field (ogf) associated to the OpCode Command Field(ocf) in any documentation (I skimmed the ~2300 pages  of the Bluetooth 4.0 core spec). If anyone knows where to search... :)

In the end, the question is: is there a way to set the address type to random (as with the hcitool command) with the kura framework ?
Or am I totally misleaded ? :/

Anyway, I'm really new to the kura and ble ecosystems so, sorry if it looks like an obvious thing to do but I feel like I'm running out of inspiration and could totally use a hand!

PS: Congrats if you made it to the end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so for those who find themselves in my position in the future, I just received an answer from the Eurotech support team.

> Dear Mr. Carneiro,
>
> [...]
>
> Regarding the random BD_ADDR, this is a configuration of the BLE device.
> So, your BLE device is advertising an address of type random, not public, and you should specify the address type on the connection string, as you already did.
> **Unfortunately, current Kura Bluetooth API doesn't provide a way to specify the type of address into the connection string. We are developing a new set of APIs for BLE that will be available on preview on the next Kura/ESF release, but the Reliagate 10-05 will not support these yet.**

Answer (score 1):

Haha lol. Kura seems to just start a gatttool process, send commands in text, and parse the output as its interface...

Here is where it is stated, using the address as parameter: https://github.com/eclipse/kura/blob/0339ac787f90debdfc270c1dee0c16de16ea6f7e/kura/org.eclipse.kura.linux.bluetooth/src/main/java/org/eclipse/kura/linux/bluetooth/util/BluetoothUtil.java#L319. Unfortunately the Kura developers seem to have missed that there is something called Random Address in the BLE standard and I don't see how that could be worked around using the current API.

Comment: Hi emil thanks tor your answer!
Yeah I saw that class, I tried to import the package org.kura.linux.bluetooth as a bundle dependencie so that I could use the method 
hcitoolCmd(String name, String[] cmd, BluetoothProcessListener listener); 
and basically "overload" the startSession() method. 
But I was getting an error when exporting the bundle saying that the classes of the bluetooth.* package were unresolved *sigh*.  
I feel that's one valid way to go though.